# Ратай и оратай

Tags: значение-слов

Пахаря называют и ратаем, и оратаем. Например:
*Земля, без граней, им свободно

Приносит жатвы и плоды,

И ратаи там лишь погодно

Проводят тучные бразды*
(В. Капнист)

И в то же время мы видим у С.Т. Аксакова:
*Вот родина моя...

Вот дикие пустыни!..

Вот благодарная оратаю земля!

Дубовые леса, и злачные долины,

И тучной жатвою покрытые поля!*

Чем ратай отличается от оратая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОРАТАЙ — ОРАТАЙ, я, муж. (стар.). То же, что ратай. (Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1992 ).
Оратай, Оратель и Ратай
Оратай, Оратель и Ратай м. устар. 1. То же, что: землепашец(Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000).
ора́тай Из ра́тай под влиянием формы ора́ть "пахать".(Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973).